# Multiple Listboxes to Select Data(table1) and Insert to MySQL Table2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, listbox

I have two tables, incldues and TIncludes which are used for storing three columns of data; An ID, macro_num, macro
The includes(table1) has all of the items possible to list, these are shown by macro_num in a listbox on the form (select1). The user can add the wanted items to the second box, select2. The listboxes populate and move the data to eachother, add/remove buttons using javascript.
I can't seem to get the data from select2 to insert into my database. Not sure what I setup incorrectly or overlooked.
Are there any working examples of such a thing? I have only seen where one item is inserted and that is fine, but I have some reports which need 40 items. 
Thanks in advance for reading this. I hope there may be a quick solution as I have not dealt with this problem before.. my first large form item requirement.

Comment: Hi Grey - welcome to StackOverflow.  Looks like you've not read the FAQ yet:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP form handler is only going to know about the options that are selected in your list. You'll need to do more than just add the items to a select element to get them to your code. You can add them to hidden elements, or you might be able to force a select-all through javascript as the form is submitted.

Comment: I tried using the hidden elements, for some reason it didn't work. I am not too familiar with Javascript but that sounds like a good idea. I will try to find some resources for a select-all at submit.